# blank master view

Tags: ios

Basically, I don't know why my main view is blank (in the Simulator).  This is my first app in iOS and am trudging up the learning curve (so thanks ahead of time).

In MainStoryboard.storyboard I have three cells laid out.  The first one has an identifier of "SoundCategoryCell" and the other two have "Cell".

I'm have the table view content as "static cells" because there will be a known, fixed number.

While I have edited cellForRowAtIndexPath I'm not sure it's relevant but will add the code if you think it's needed.

I'm confused as to why the 'picture' of the master view controller has three cells in it in the storyboard but it's blank after build.

Thanks again..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have removed all the TableView DataSource methods from the scene's parent class:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Having these in the parent class will cause issues when using Static Cell tableviews.  You still need a UITableViewController parent class for the storyboard scene, but you don't need the datasource methods

Comment: That did it!  I would think that Xcode should have commented out the necessary methods when switching from Dynamic to Static but I'm still rather new at this.